# Tips for beginning 3D Application Development

Tags: 3d

guys I want to create an application that has a 3D display. I want all the planets in it. Then the next step is I want to have satellites in it as well. I want to provide an interface to add satellites etc.

Off course this will include 3D designing and it will be more like a game.

I want to know what are the things I need to know to make this.. you know, give me like a list: 3D modeling, OpenGL etc.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question a bit? If you're just after a list, Google is your best friend.

Comment: Have you any preference for a language to use?

Comment: nopes.. i will learn which will provide the most utilities for graphics and secure networking

Comment: Do you have any previous experience with any 3D framework? Programming language? Anything would help us with giving you a more suitable answer. `:]`

Comment: well i use "Google Sketchup" a lot.. but that doesn't fit the criteria of 3D framework etc.. i have studied 3D designing and all but havent really worked on it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct 3D (it is better if you want to have your app running on Win, will avoid a lot of issues with OGL)
3D Math\Geometry (Matrices, etc.)

If that will be only planets, then you can use built in shapes, like sphere. If you will have space ships, or anything else, then you should look into 3d editors, like Milkshape 3D(good for beginners), 3ds max or Maya for complex models, or Blender.

That's it for beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Some UI design knowledge (hard to describe where to pick this up, but study some UIs in various games / applications)  The more things you need to do, the more you need to study how to sort/ categorize.

Something to help your write 3D (at least the rendering side). Rolling your own engine is a VERY good way to get practice, but is time consuming and probably not what you want right now.

Some basic 3D Math. You will probably want to click on planets I am assuming? You will want to be able to test a line and see what planets are being hit by it for your UI.

IF you want do something besides simple sphere with no texture (for example you need the red spot on Jupiter), then any 3D art program (I suggest 3DSMax, but I am a programmer so I dislike Maya). There's lots of other cheaper ones out there.. what you want to do is really basic so anything that will even let you apply a texture will work.
Unreal has enough built in abilities that you can simply apply a texture to a sphere and have your planet details.

Comment: i am already doing  XNA C#, i need to learn how to add custom UI Controls to the 3D App which is basically a 3D game, you see i don't want to have a limit with the Interface and Visual Display so my current strategy is to make an App out of a 3D Game.